# how to merge 2 pending changelist with common files

Tags: perforce

I have a pending CL in my workspace with files 'A', 'B', 'C'.
I have a local uncommitted changelist saved on my disk with files 'A', 'C', 'D'.
So while merging this local CL with p4merge to the existing workspace, it shows following error,
"file already checked out in this workspace"
Is there a proper way to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the scenario.  You have two Perforce workspaces set up with pending local work, and you want to transfer from one workspace to the other?  Shelving would be the trick there.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what a local uncommitted changelist means here.

If I consider the CL with files  'A', 'C', 'D' to be another pending CL in same Work Space in which you have the pending CL with files 'A', 'B', 'C', then I think a force integration or merge can help you...